# Basis for $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ that Solves the Heat Equation

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, brownian-motion, heat-equation, hermite-polynomials

This is a less-than-serious question that I asked on math.SE, but I suspect it is slightly more appropriate to ask it here. Consider the heat equation $$
u_t = \frac12 u_{xx}
$$ On $\mathbb{T}$ with Lebesgue measure $\frac{dx}{2\pi}$, $L^2(\mathbb{T})$ has the $\sqrt{2}\sin(nx)$ and $\sqrt{2}\cos(nx)$ as an orthonormal basis and the modifications $e^{-2n^2t}\sqrt{2}\sin(nx)$ and $e^{-2n^2t}\sqrt{2}\cos(nx)$ solve the heat equation. Consequently, for any $f \in L^2(\mathbb{T})$ we have the expansion
$$
f(x) = a_0 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n \sqrt{2}\cos(nx) + \sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n\sqrt{2}\sin(nx)
$$
and the heat evolution of $f$ looks like
$$
f(x,t) = a_0 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n e^{-2n^2t}\sqrt{2}\cos(nx) + \sum_{n=1}^\infty b_ne^{-2n^2t}\sqrt{2}\sin(nx)
$$
Now move to $\mathbb{R}$. The Hermite polynomials (in probability) are defined as 
$$
H_n'(x) = (-1)^n e^{x^2/2} \frac{\partial^n}{\partial x^n}\left[e^{-x^2/2}\right]
$$ and form an orthonormal basis for the weighted $L^2$ space with measure $e^{-x^2/2}dx$. The modified Hermite polynomials are given by 
$$
H_n(x,t) = (-t)^n e^{x^2/2t} \frac{\partial^n}{\partial x^n}\left[e^{-x^2/2t}\right]
$$ These polynomials in $x$ and $t$ solve the backwards heat equation and occur in probability since $H_n(B_t,t)$ is a martingale for standard brownian motion $B_t$. For instance, $H_2(x,t) = x^2 - t$ and $B_t^2 - t$ is a martingale. Note that $H_n'(x) = H_n(x,1)$.

Now if $f$ is a function on $\mathbb{R}$ with $f(x)e^{-x^2/2} \in L^2(\mathbb{R})$ then we can expand $f$ in terms of Hermite polynomials 
$$
f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n H_n(x,1)
$$
where convergence is in the weighted $L^2$ space with measure $e^{-x^2/2}dx$. One would like to say that the heat evolution of $f$ would be the function 
$$
f(x,t) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n H_n(x,1-t)
$$ 
I would like to be able to use the Hermite polynomials to construct a basis for regular $L^2(\mathbb{R})$, whose terms have conveniently expressible heat evolution. For instance, the modification 
$$
G_n(x,t) = \frac{1}{t^{1/2+n}} e^{-x^2/2t} H_n(x,t)
$$ solve the heat equation since 
$$
\frac{1}{t^{1/2+n}} e^{-x^2/2t} H_n(x,t) = \frac{1}{t^{1/2+n}} e^{-x^2/2t} (-t)^n e^{x^2/2t}\frac{\partial^n}{\partial x^n}\left[e^{-x^2/2t}\right]
=
\frac{\partial^n}{\partial x^n}\left[\frac1{\sqrt{t}}e^{-x^2/2t}\right]
$$ and the inside solves the heat equation. The issue is that the factor of $e^{-x^2/2t}$ is too large, because then we have 
$$
G_n(x,t)G_m(x,t) = H_n(x,t)H_m(x,t) e^{-x^2/t}
$$ and when $t=1$ this does not produce an orthogonal set of functions since the correct weight is $e^{-x^2/2}$ not $e^{-x^2}$. If we attempt to make some modification $e^{-x^2/4t}H_n(x,t)$ then it is not clear what additional factor is needed in order to solve the heat equation.

**Question:** Is there a convenient basis for $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ whose terms have some kind of easy to write down heat evolution?

Comment: It seems like you're looking for eigenfunctions of $\frac{d^2}{dx^2}$ on $L^2(\mathbb{R})$, which is a problem because it doesn't have any.  Things work on $\mathbb{T}$ because it's compact and so the second derivative has compact resolvent.

Comment: @NateEldredge: But is you do not use the Lebesgue measure but a Gaussian one, the Hermite polynomials become good eigenfunctions.

Comment: @AndrásBátkai: But then $-d^2/dx^2$ is not self-adjoint on $L^2(\mathbb R, e^{-x^2}\, dx)$.

Comment: @ChristianRemling: yes, this is why I did not write an answer but only a (not tooo clever) comment.

Comment: I think it'll be straightforward to make a proof (of impossibility) out of Nate's remark, along these lines: your only chance would be to evolve an initial ONB $H_n$ by the heat flow, but then, to keep the time evolved vectors orthogonal, you must have $0=\langle e^{t\Delta}H_m, e^{t\Delta}H_n\rangle =\langle H_m, e^{2t\Delta} H_n\rangle$, so $e^{2t\Delta}H_n$ must be a multiple of $H_n$, but we know this is impossible.